# Map a Conic to the Normalized Image Plane

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, projective-geometry

I have a problem with understanding a specific operation related to the mapping of an ellipse, captured by a camera, to a plane:

According to this [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6826500), given the [calibration matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_resectioning) $K$ of a camera, a [symmetric conic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Homogeneous_coordinates) $C'$ can be mapped to a conic $C = K^T C' K$ on the *normalized image plane*.

I do not understand what the operation $K^T C' K$ is doing and what this *normalized image plane* might correspond to. Any comment to help me understand what is happening geometrically with this operation would be appreciated.

Note: I did notice that $K^T$ is a lower triangular matrix, $K$ is an upper triangular matrix, and $C'$ is symmetric (not diagonal) but I am unsure of what to do with this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply the way that bilinear forms are transformed by a coordinate transformation. The original conic has the homogeneous coordinate matrix equation $\mathbf x'^TC'\mathbf x'=0$. The calibration matrix gives you a transformation $\mathbf x'=K\mathbf x$ from points on the normalized image plane to the original image plane. Substituting this into the first equation, you get $(K\mathbf x)^TC'(K\mathbf x) = \mathbf x^T(K^TC'K)\mathbf x=0$, therefore the conic on the normalized image plane is represented by the matrix $K^TC'K$.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot!